# Generic table structure for storing files/images in database

Tags: php, database-design

What fields do you think I need to store/retrieve files generically?

I am thinking:

- name (varchar)
- data (blob)
- content_type (varchar)

Also, is there a way in php to programmatically determine content-type when file is uploaded?

(I have already asked the question files in file system or database and I have chosen to go with database.)

Comment: What database are you using? I cringe when people shove BLOB into databases, in particular MySQL.

Comment: I know that this is probably not what you want to hear, but I am going to say it anyway - using a database to store files is a mistake. You are better using the database to store metadata for the files (things you may want to search on, or record - title, tags, description, date uploaded, user uploaded, etc.), but files are almost always better stored as files. Even if you store the files under a filename which keys them to the database row (so as to avoid filename clashes, etc.), this would be better than trying to store the whole file into a database field.

Comment: I have already started a question about that topic. I am using a database to make my application easy to install (no chmod'ing files) and easy backups. It is actually only one image for now, so it isn't a big deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with:

- file_id (INT, auto-increment PRIMARY)
- file_name (VARCHAR 255)
- file_data(LONGBLOB)

Answer (score 0):

`BLOB` is for store files

Depends of the app requirements but I think is not a good idea to store file in the database